# Add TextView after LineChart

Tags: java, android, xml, android-layout

Okey guys i have LineChart made with achartengine, here is screenshot:

https://www.dropbox.com/s/yk5nipe3b6upcaa/11414548_10205801109521047_408896835_n.jpg?dl=0

**1st XML**

```
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

    </LinearLayout>
    <TextView
        android:layout_below="@+id/linearLayout1"
        android:id="@+id/description"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:text="Description:"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        />
    <TextView
        android:layout_below="@+id/description"
        android:id="@+id/descriptionText"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

**2ndXML**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">


    <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/linearLayout1" android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="0dip" android:layout_weight="1"/>


    <LinearLayout android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <TextView

            android:id="@+id/description"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:text="Description:"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            />
        <TextView

            android:id="@+id/descriptionText"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Here is code for onCreate() method:

```
 description=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.descriptionText);
    description.setText("sadasdasdas");

    setRendererStyling();
    if (mChartView == null) {
        LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.linearLayout1);
        mChartView = ChartFactory.getLineChartView(this, mDataset,
                mRenderer);
        mRenderer.setSelectableBuffer(100);
        layout.addView(mChartView, new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
    } else
        mChartView.repaint();
```

My problem is that I want to put two TextViews after chart.I tried with this two different xml and no result.

I am only getting Description: on my activity...

**EDIT FOR Dharm**

```
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_above="@+id/scrollView">

    </LinearLayout>

    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/scrollView"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" >
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent">
                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/description"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="Description:"
                        android:textStyle="bold"
                        />
                    <TextView
                        android:layout_below="@+id/description"
                        android:id="@+id/descriptionText"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a RelativeLayout and arrange the graph to have its bottom align with the top of your TextViews. Your first xml is close, but it is creating a LinearLayout that fills the screen and then placing the TextView below that.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_above="@+id/description">

    </LinearLayout>
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/description"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Description:"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" />
    <TextView
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/description"
        android:id="@+id/descriptionText"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Tnx @dharms this worked.But now i have one more question:

In second TextView text is bigger 7,8 lines maybe...and i can't place it below first TextView there is not enough space so  maybe good solution is with ScrollView i tried something but no good.U can see how i use scrolview in edited post